# allow anonymous access to the job's config.xml in Jenkins

Tags: configuration, installation, jenkins

I want to switch our Jenkins to server to a better machine. The new Jenkins is installed and configured, but without the jobs. I planned to use Jenkins job import plugin in order to import all the jobs, but I have a small problem. My old jenkins installation requires login in order to see the config.xml, even though the anonymous user has read permission on the jobs. Currently I get HTTP error 403 on the old jenkins, and a NullPointerException in the Job Import plugin.

How can I move all the Jobs? I have about 50 jobs, so setting them one by one is saved as the last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better just copying over all the job configs. These will be in $JENKINS_HOME/jobs - copy that whole directory to your new instance or, if you don't want the build history, just copy the job subdirectories and their config.XML files. Then restart Jenkins and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution with job import plugin. i have enabled the admin access for anonymous user and its started working.

make sure you have enabled the admin access to anonymous user, it should work.

Comment: Too late for me... maybe it can help someone else